# Can a knot be cables of two different knots?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds

I wonder if there is an example of a knot $K$ in the 3-sphere which can be realized as cables of two distinct (up to isotopy) knots $K_1 \neq K_2$.

It is known that if a knot $K$ is the $(p,q)$-cable of another knot $K'$, then there is a unique annulus in its exterior $X_K$ with slope $pq$ on $\partial X_K$. This is the only restriction on possible cabling configurations of $K$ that I am aware of. Can we somehow argue that $K'$ is uniquely determined by $K$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, $K'$ is uniquely determined by $K$ and so, no, a knot cannot be a cable in two different ways.  This follows from the [Gordon-Luecke theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon%E2%80%93Luecke_theorem) and from a result of [Feustel and Whitten](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v30/cjm1978v30.1284-1295.pdf).  See Lemma 5 in this paper of [Malyutin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.03368.pdf).

Comment: As soon as it is known that one can recover $p$ and $q$ from $K_{p,q}$, the result also follows from the Corollary  of Theorem 2 in Soma's *On preimage knots in $\mathbb{S}^3$*
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-100-03/S0002-9939-1987-0891169-7/S0002-9939-1987-0891169-7.pdf